# copying a file to multiple machines

Tags: linux, shell

Is it possible to copy a file on multiple remote machines through scp in one command?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`rdist`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_rdist.htm).

Answer (score 1):

[PSSH](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) provides a variety of tools that can do ssh, scp, rsync, etc operations on a cluster of machines.

Comment: Is it possible to use wildcard characters with IP addresses in scp

Comment: @shweta, not with `scp` itself. (a) You need to take direct yes/no action over every initial connection with `scp` (b) `scp` itself sure won't do this, as @raghuram points out, which is why there are a variety of tools like `pssh` to automate connecting to multiple machines simultaneously.